# Angular + Apache CXF for RDBMS access or Angular + Spring MVC?

Tags: angularjs, spring

I have to write a simple web-application which basically fetches data from RDBMS, does some computations on the data and displays the results on screen.

There is a reference application from which I need to re-use components. 
I have come up with two options -

First - To use Angular.js for creating the views which calls REST based web services exposed by the server side using Apache CXF. REST based services hit the DB, process the data and return it to the client side.

Second - To use Angular.js for creating the views which calls Spring MVC based controllers. Controllers hit the DB, process the data and return it to the client side.

I only have experience in Spring MVC + tiles based JSP for views, so, I was initially inclined with the second approach, but upon further thinking, I think that the first approach is better since I can let the application be driven from the client side for flow routing and let the client side be dependent on REST bases services rather than being tied up to the Spring MVC framework.

it will really help me if somebody can provide me some more inputs...  thanks in advance...

Comment: The approach I always use and works best for the projects I worked on is to implement Backend with (Spring+Hibernate) - Rest Web-Service and then access them in Angular js using $http. It works like charm

Comment: @YashikaGarg - Thanks for your comment. I have one question though. If your app exposes a RESTful web-service, then what role does spring play in your application? is it only for DI or are you using it for MVC?

Comment: Yes I am using it for MVC

Answer (score 0):

Working with Rest expose your services, to any level including your application as well. If in future anyone else needs you services, you can easily expose it using REST. So in my view, working with REST is more beneficial and rest depends on your business case.

Moreover you can combine both approaches. use REST to expose your services and MVC for separation of concerns and avoiding tightly coupled data and business logic.

Comment: are you talking about the angular's MVC or Spring's MVC?

Comment: I am talking for : Spring MVC